# need help installing WebSphere commerce 8 with script

Tags: batch-file, websphere-commerce, commerce

Hi im installing WebSphere Commerce 8 on 4 computers and its a bit time consuming, im thinking a great way to save time would be to script it so that i save some time and can be used for future installations. 
Do any of you have it scripted?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can script the installation of WebSphere Commerce using a response file, see the IBM Knowledge Center topic [Installing WebSphere Commerce Developer silently](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_8.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.install.doc/tasks/tigdevtoolkit_silent.htm)